# In haskell. how to solve splitList into a tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples

`splitList n xs`: splits a list `xs` in to a tuple of two lists based on the provided index `n`.

Examples:

```
splitList 3 [1..5] ⇒ ([1,2,3], [4,5])
splitList 3 [1..] ⇒ ([1,2,3], [4..])
splitList 9 [] ⇒ ([], [])
```

How do I solve it ?

Comment: You're looking for `Data.List.splitAt`.

Comment: why do you vandalize your own question here?

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible solution:

```
splitList :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitList _ [] = ([], [])
splitList n xs = (take n xs, drop n xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])

λ> splitAt 3 [1..5]
([1,2,3],[4,5])
```